# How do I get NFS for glusterfs working on Oracle Linux 8?

Tags: linux, nfs, oracle-linux, glusterfs

I want to use glusterfs to provide storage for a *lot* of files. Millions that must appear to be in one NFS exported directory.  I installed the software, configured it and started the cluster.  However, I cannot get NFS working.

1. Create the file /etc/ganesha/exports/export.volume01.conf containing.

```
EXPORT{
    Export_Id = 10100 ;
    Path = "/data/glusterfs/brick01";

    FSAL {
        name = GLUSTER;
        hostname = "scagfs01.lereta.net";
        volume = "volume01"
    }

    Access_type = RW;
    Squash = root_squash;
    Disable_ACL = TRUE;
    Pseudo = "/filestore";
    Protocols = "3","4";
    Transports = "UDP","TCP" ;
    SecType = "sys";
}
```

2. Add to /etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf

```
%include "/etc/ganesha/exports/export.volume01.conf"
```

3. Restart nfs-ganesha

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-ganesha
```

According to everything I've read I should now have an exported volume but showmount disagrees

```
sudo showmount -e scagfs01.lereta.net
Export list for scagfs01.lereta.net:
```

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

- OS is Oracle Linux 8.6
- glusterfs is version 8.6
- nfs-ganesha is version 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was basic syntax errors. I found where ganesha was logging (/var/log/ganesha/ganesha.log" on my system) and the answer was there.

1. A missing semicolon in /etc/ganesha/exports/export.volume01.conf

   `volume = "volume01"` -> `volume = "volume01";`
2. An extra semicolon in /etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf

   `%include "/etc/ganesha/exports/export.volume01.conf";` -> `%include "/etc/ganesha/exports/export.volume01.conf"`

Things are so much more simple once you know the answer :)